# PowerShell Memory Usage for Tomcat

Tags: powershell, tomcat, memory, grouping

I have been digging on this for a while.  I think am pretty close, but I am having trouble in trying to show the WS.

I did find what seems pretty relevant to showing memory per application

http://www.lmftfy.com/index.php/powershell-get-memory-used-by-a-group-of-processes/

https://foobarcode.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/memory-usage-grouped-by-process-name/

```
ps tomcat* -ComputerName computerA | Group ProcessName | Select @{Label="Mem";Expression={($_.group |Measure WorkingSet -sum).Sum / 1MB }} | Sort Mem
```

And this works fine.

```
Mem
---
4.109375
1006.9453125
1388.453125
```

So...  We want to loop through a number of computers:

```
  $procs = get-process tomcat* -ComputerName computerA
   foreach ($proc in $procs){
    $WorkingSet = '{0:N0}' -f [int](Group ProcessName | Select (@{Label="Mem";Expression={($proc.group |Measure WorkingSet -sum).Sum / 1MB }}) )
    $VirtualMem = '{0:N0}' -f [int]($proc.VM/1MB)
        write-host 'WS' $WorkingSet
        write-host 'VM' $VirtualMem
}
```

We know the WS is not 0..

I think I have a formatting issue with the WS..

```
WS 0
VM 1,523
WS 0
VM 60
WS 0
VM 1,917
```

I thought I was pretty close in this..

```
$procs = get-process tomcat* -ComputerName computerA
   foreach ($proc in $procs){
   $name = $proc.MachineName
   $process = $proc.ProcessName
   $WorkingSet = '{0:N0}' -f [int]($proc.WS/1MB)
   $VirtualMem = '{0:N0}' -f [int]($proc.VM/1MB)
   write-host $name $process 'WS' $WorkingSet 'VM' $VirtualMem
}
```

However, I am getting negative values when using this..

```
Tomcat Memory Usage Report - 04/14/2016                         
#   Server  Process ID (PID)    Process Name    Working Set(Kb) Virtual Memory(Mb)  
25  Server24    5876    tomcat6 1,471   -251    
26  Server25    5832    tomcat6 -1,536  -1,118  
27  Server26    1824    tomcat6 -1,497  -1,133  
28  Server27    7916    tomcat6 1,661   -1,013  
29  Server28    6340    tomcat6 888 1,690   
30  Server29    6700    tomcat6 -1,242  1,611   
31  Server30    9880    Tomcat6 1,007   1,523
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help any?

```
(Get-Counter -ListSet Process | Get-Counter) |
Where {$_.InstanceName -eq 'TomCat' -and $_.path -like '*working set*'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$proc.workingset64` if you get negative values in 64-bit systems